# Passing id on views

Tags: python, django

I would like to pass the id of an organization, in a view function that doesn't pass an id.

1. Views.py

```
def OrgForm_view(request):  

    if request.method == 'POST':
        post=Organization()
        post.orgname= request.POST.get('name')
        post.address = request.POST.get('address')

        post.save()

        return redirect('/results_view/')

    else:
            
        return render(request,'index.html')


def results_view(request, organization_id):  

    orgz = Organization.objects.get(id=organization_id)

    context = {'orgz': orgz}

    return render(request, "results.html", context)
```

2. Urls.py

```
    path('OrgForm/', OrgForm_view, name="OrgForm"),
    path(r'results_view/<int:organization_id>/', views.results_view, name="results_view"),
```

3. The error when I don't pass an id

```
Reverse for 'results_view' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['results_view\\/(?P<organization_id>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

4. The error I get when I pass an id (return redirect('/results_view/{{orgz.id}}')

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/results_view/%7B%7Borgz.id%7D%7D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
from django.urls import reverse

return redirect(reverse('results_view', kwargs={"organization_id": post.pk}))
```

Comment: @zero...hey. Do you mind checking this out for me too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856954/using-class-method-data-in-charts