# Django - object is not subscriptable django charts.js" or nothing displays at all?

Tags: python, django, chart.js

i'm trying to display data on my charts using some model values and charts.js. My values are a country field and a class method that i'm not sure how I'm to call it.

I keep getting the error

> "TypeError: 'Organization' object is not subscriptable django
> charts.js" or nothing displays at all. Please help.

models.py

```
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class Organization(models.Model):
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')

    def Total_Score(cls):
        Total_Score = cls.grants_score() + cls.internal_score() #This is a sum of other class methods. This part works as is.
        return Total_Score
```

Views.py

```
def scores_charts(request):

    labels = []
    data = []

    orgz = Organization.objects.values('country').annotate(Total_Scores=Organization.objects.values('Total_Scores()'))
    
    for org in orgz:
        labels.append(org['country'])
        labels.append(org['Total_Scores'])
    
    return JsonResponse(data={
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
    })
```

Template.html

```
<div class="card-block-big">
  <canvas id="scores_charts" data-url="{% url 'scores_charts' %}"></canvas> 
</div>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>

          <script>
        
            $(function () {
        
              var $scores_charts = $("#scores_charts");
              $.ajax({
                url: $scores_charts.data("url"),
                success: function (data) {
        
                  var ctx = $scores_charts[0].getContext("2d");
        
                  new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                      labels: data.labels,
                      datasets: [{
                        label: 'Scores',
                        backgroundColor: 'blue',
                        data: data.data
                      }]          
                    },
                    options: {
                      responsive: true,
                      legend: {
                        position: 'top',
                      },
                      title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Scores Bar Chart'
                      }
                    }
                  });
        
                }
              });
        
            });
        
          </script>
```

Comment: in your "scores_charts" function of views.py, you are never appending any value to "data" list, your both appends are for "labels" list, is this a typing mistake or thats how it is?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 No it didn't...I have tried so many things so far. The countries pick up, but the Total_Scores() method doesn't.

Comment: @ClaudiaNjeri probably thats where the error likely is. You should try something like `vals = Total_Scores() 

Total_Scores=Organization.objects.values(vals)`

Answer (score 0):

This error

> "TypeError: 'Organization' object is not subscriptable django charts.js"

suggests that you are trying to get an element out of an Organization object that isn't a `dictionary`, `list`, or a `tuple`.

I suspect the likely cause of this may be stemming from the following (though you can confirm this with the full error trace which should tell you the line of code that is causing the error):

```
for org in orgz:
  labels.append(org['country'])
  labels.append(org['Total_Scores'])
```

You should try to debug the values of this and verify that they are correct.